# How can I find the Win8 key when running Ubuntu on my machine

Tags: windows-8

Ive installed Ubuntu on my Lenovo machine that had a preinstalled Win8 on it, now I need to reinstall it since I would like to run a dual boot machine but Windows have hidden the key in the BIOS.

Any ideas on how find it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Execute the command

```
sudo hexdump -s 56 -e '"MSDM key: " /29 "%s\n"'  /sys/firmware/acpi/tables/MSDM
```